# How do I send a set of youtube URLs from a Mac to the youtube app on Apple TV?

Tags: data-synchronization, appletv

On my Macbook I note a series of youtube URLs that I would like to watch, sometime.

They are extended documentaries, and so I'd like to watch them on the TV. The TV is hooked to an Apple TV (4th gen).

I could of course use the youtube app on the Apple TV to search again for the URLs, but this is terribly tedious. It's a task best done on a computer.

How do I send a set of youtube URLs from a Mac to the youtube app on Apple TV?

*Yes, I am aware that I could use AirPlay.* But doing so inevitably requires me to run back and forth between the Mac and the Apple TV.

I could also send the URLs via Google Keep to my iPad, and AirPlay from the iPad to the Apple TV, but I'm hoping there is a way that turns the Apple TV into a standalone device, without requiring me to type the URLs by hand.

Comment: I assume that you are logged into YouTube on both the Mac and the AppleTV?

Comment: Ah.. you are suggesting that Google has built into youtube a solution for this problem. I do not need to be logged into youtube (I dislike tracking) to view these URLs, but it sounds that logging in would make the list appear on the AppleTV, provided I'm logged in there using the same account. I'm tempted to ask: must this list be a public one? But that would be wholly outside the scope of this forum.

Comment: If you use the same account on the Mac and the AppleTV the list can be private.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your Apple TV YouTube app, you should see an option to activate.. To login to your YouTube account.  Once you follow the instructions displayed on your TV, you should then be logged into your YouTube account and on your TV you can see your favorites and playlists etc.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to comment to your question about playlists being public so I will comment here.  They do not need to be public. You can watch any of your playlists on Apple TV

Comment: Adding some details: In the menu you'll only see "My Channel", "Trending", "Subscriptions", "History", and "Watch Later", but nothing related to playlists. Go to https://www.youtube.com/view_all_playlists to view/edit your playlists. They do indeed move to your AppleTV, and with a nice interface to boot (requiring entering a key on your desktop, not on the AppleTV).